# How can I marshal content to a file asynchronously using JAXB

Tags: java, file, jaxb

I have an object that i want to marshal using JAXB and write into a file **asynchronously**.

I tried to write the content (of approximative 300mb) and then use AsynchronousFileChannel to write the file.
Unfortunalty it launches a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space during marshalling

```
  protected String getFormattedFileContent(T fileContent) throws Exception {
     StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
     final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(fileContent.getClass());
     final Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
     jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
     jaxbMarshaller.marshal(fileContent, stringWriter);
     return stringWriter.toString();
  }
```

**Edit :** The marshalling takes a long time to marshal the big object into XML so i launched the marshalling and the writing file into a separate Thread

Comment: are you sure you need whole XML from 300MB as full string before writing to a file? what if you marshal your object right into FileWriter (opened by AsynchronousFileChannel) instead of StringWriter first?

Comment: From what i saw it's useable only with Path and ByteBuffer, can you put an example with FileWriter openned with AsynchronousFileChannel ?

Comment: Sorry did not look closer at first time. But, do you really need write file asynchronously? Just standard FileWriter is not enough? I'm asking because JAXB Marshaller is synchronous and has only listener which I guess will not help you. So, it looks like you need to make your own OutputStream or Writer implementation which will handle Asynchronous file writing out of its write methods - put byte(s) into buffer, write into channel, clear the buffer... Still does it worth to do, rather than run marshaller in separate thread? also I'm quite not sure about holding POJO of 300MB for marshalling.

Comment: Actually marshalling the object was very long also, so I put the marshalling and the file writing in a separate Thread.Anyway could be nice if JAXB could provide a way to marshall and write a file in a non blocking way

Comment: Maybe it will be good, but inXML

Comment: Maybe it will be good, but in XML world there are no many cases when it is needed, so it is not a concern for JDK framework. My concern is to have JAXB working on it you need to have that object fully loaded in memory first. You may explore other ways to translate those data to elements and write them into file on the fly. And you can do it in separate ashyncronous thread. Something like DOM document or in XSLT transformation... It is just a thought ...